# What is a typical situation to say "disgraziato"?

Tags: word-usage, adjectives

What is a typical situation to use "disgraziato!"?

What kind of emotion is associated with the word?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

"Disgraziato" is equivalent to "wretched" and it can be associated with different feelings: it may be about someone who has done something very *very* wrong and you think they should feel ashamed by that; it may be about a very unlucky person and you feel sorry for them; or it may be about a person who is behaving cheeky and you have a benevolent feeling about it (for example a child who is being a "rascal").

Answer (score 4):

The usage you're probably asking about is the one where you address the word to someone whose behavior you want to criticize/condemn or deprecate. It has also other uses, but as far as your question is concerned, that's basically it.

Comment: The negative use is not the only one. Two other common uses are 1) as a joke, e.g. with a friend (*Disgraziato! Non ti fai più sentire!*) 2) used in a "cute" way, e.g. to a child (*Hai mangiato tutta la torta? Disgraziato!*).

Comment: @nico Sure, but I was addressing the OP's question which to me looked about the dramatic one. There are even more uses than the ones you listed. :P

Comment: I cannot really feel that the OP is referring to that specific situation though... Really this is one situation where body language would tell way more than any dictionary! :)

Comment: @nico True, body language helps. :P But the question asks about "what is the typical situation", and considering the quote, what other than the dramatic use? If the question had asked for related uses I might have listed those as well.

Comment: well, I mostly use *disgraziato* in a joking way as I feel it's kind of a *retro insult*. It is difficult to define a typical situation, also because I am pretty sure there will be regionality issues in the use of the word (I would say you hear it more often in the South than in the North)

Answer (score 2):

1) Image this scene: You are 7, ate all -for example marmalade- that your mum need to do something. Then she discover it and starts to scream: "Disgraziato! Che hai fatto?"
In this case your mum is growling at you but she is not really only angry, but also a little bit wry. I think in souther Italy "disgraziato" is used also in more severe situation (100% angry and a wooden shoe flying to you).

2) You saw a really unlucky person, maybe he lost all his money or someone of his family recently died and you say, in a sad tone (and not directly to him, it can be offensive): "Che disgraziato, è stato proprio sfortunato."

3) As a joke, like with a friend.